# How to modify a list in Numba without completely destroying performance?

Tags: python, performance, list, copy, numba

Here's an example. If you run this code, it will print that it took on the order of ~1 second to call `foo`:

```
import timeit
import numba

@numba.njit('void(List(intp, True))')
def foo(v): v[0] += 1

a = range(1 << 25)
start = timeit.default_timer()
foo(a)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start
```

Obviously Numba is copying the list back and forth. Is there any way for me to avoid it?
(I can't easily use a NumPy array since I need the list to be resizable elsewhere in my code.)

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's the motivation?

Comment: @Veedrac: What do you mean? You can't imagine scenarios where people need a list that isn't a fixed size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use a list with Numba, and the copy is too expensive, you're going to need to compile this function in object mode. nopython mode can't operate on a list directly; doing so is fundamentally a Python object operation, the thing nopython mode prohibits.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the point of using Numba? The whole point of the function is to operate on the list, so it wouldn't be any faster if I just do it in Python mode right? Is there really no way to do this?.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Numba might be able to do some [loop-jitting](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/glossary.html#term-loop-jitting) (not possible in your example), or it could use calls like `PyList_GetItem` and `PyList_SetItem` to avoid dynamic dispatch (I don't know if it knows how to do that), but it's likely that you'll see no benefit over an ordinary Python function.

Comment: I think Cython can do some of this better; for example, I think Cython offers better interoperability with the Python standard library `array` module, which is sort of between lists and NumPy arrays in a way that might be appropriate for your use case.